# How can I trigger a 'focusout' after I click on an element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, combobox

I have the following markup:

```
<select style="display:none">
    <option value='1'>1</option>
    <option vlaue='2'>2</option>
</select>
<input type="text" id="comboBox" />
<ul id="comboBoxData" style="display:none">
    <li id='1'>1</li>
    <li id='2'>2</li>
</ul>
```

and the following JQuery code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('select').each(function() {
        var parent = this;
        $('#comboBoxData').on('click', 'li', function() {
            var value = $(this).prop('id');
            $(parent).val(value);
            $('#comboBox').val(value);
        });
    });   
    $('#comboBox').bind('focusin', function () {
        $('#comboBoxData').show();
    });   
    $('#comboBox').bind('focusout', function () {
        $('#comboBoxData').hide();
    });
});
```

When I click on one of the LI's the 'comboBoxData' element disappears before the click trigger happens. Is there a way around this or an alternate event that I can use instead to have the same effect as a focusout?

Comment: `When I click on one of the LI's the 'comboBoxData' element disappears before the click trigger happens.`
Did not understand this.

Comment: #comboboxdata li has a click event that is not happening because the focusout event is happening before it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put mouseenter and mouseleave events and change the value of a global variable say isOver.

```
$('select').each(function() {
    var parent = this;
    $('#comboBoxData').on('click', 'li', function() {
        var value = $(this).prop('id');
        $(parent).val(value);
        $('#comboBox').val(value);
        $('#comboBoxData').hide();
    });
}); 
$('#comboBoxData').mouseover(function(){
    isOver = true;
}).mouseleave(function(){
    isOver = false;
});
$('#comboBox').bind('focusin', function () {
    $('#comboBoxData').show();
});   
$('#comboBox').bind('focusout', function () {
    if(!isOver){
        $('#comboBoxData').hide();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You do not require this:

```
 $('#comboBox').bind('focusout', function () {
        $('#comboBoxData').hide();
 });
```

instead use this inside `$('#comboBoxData').on('click', 'li', function() {`

if you are fine with plugin , you could just use this way:

```
$('#menu').bind('clickoutside', function (event) {
    $(this).hide();
});
```

You can get that plugin  [here](http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-outside-events-plugin/)

Also, I have changed the code without using the plugin:
Please check the updated answer:

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/vZwRk/32/)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I'll certainly do that but additionally I need it to disappear also when the user clicks away from it

Comment: @William Calleja  Let me know if the updated answer works fine for you?

Answer (score 0):

try with `blur()` function

```
$('#comboBox').blur(function () {
        $('#comboBoxData').hide();
    });
```

> The blur event is sent to an element when it loses focus.

from http://api.jquery.com/blur/

Comment: I tried to use blur instead however the same exact result is occuring, the blur event is happening before the click event triggers.

Comment: maybe try replacing #comboBox by #comboBoxData

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly elegant but it works.

```
$("body").click(function(event){   
    if(!$(event.target).is("#comboBoxData") && !$(event.target).is("#comboBox") ){    
        $("#comboBoxData").hide(); }
}); 


$(document).ready(function() {
    $('select').each(function() {
        $('#comboBoxData').on('click', 'li', function() {
        var value = $(this).prop('id');
                $('#comboBox').val(value);
           $('#comboBoxData').hide();
        });
    });   

    $('#comboBox').bind('focusin', function () {
    $('#comboBoxData').show();
  });
});
```